# How to update post meta with xml data

Tags: post-meta, xml

I am trying to get this to work, but it doesn't. What is wrong?

```
$tutorgeocodesrc = "http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?location=" . urlencode($tutoraddressfull) . "&appid=...";
$tutorgeocode    = simplexml_load_file($tutorgeocodesrc);
$tutorlat        = $tutorgeocode->Result[0]->latitude;
$tutorlng        = $tutorgeocode->Result[0]->longitude;
foreach($tutorgeocode->Result[0]->latitude as $child) 
{
    update_post_meta($user_id, 'tutorcords', $tutorlat);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On which hook of WP init this code part?

`$user_id` - why and from how is this var value?
`update_post_meta()` will use the post ID, see [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta).